# Windows 10 Powershell opens in C:\WINDOWS\system32 instead of folder that I shift-right-clicked in File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-explorer

I shift-right-click a folder in File Explorer and click "Open powershell window here" but it opens in:
C:\WINDOWS\system32 instead

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The context-menu entry in the registry is badly configured.

The following `.reg` file should repair it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell]
@="Open PowerShell window Here"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%L'"
```

I suggest first to use `regedit` and compare the above with the contents at key
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\powershellmenu`,
before running it.

Comment: Edited to fix doubled-up slashes & add `\Background\` to registry path. You really don't need to supply a path to registered apps but tt doesn't hurt.